# Getting data from the last 12 month using mysql

Tags: mysql, database, count

I have the following data structure in my table:

```
id member_from member_till
1  2014/03/01  2014/05/18
2  2014/01/09  2014/08/13
...
```

How can i get a count of active members for the last 12 month, grouped by month?

Ex:

```
...
2014/12/01,5
2015/01/01,12
```

As a future development is it possible to make the count the average of the first and last day of each month?

Comment: how can you find that member is active or not? you have any flag?

Comment: A member is active between the 2 dates.

Comment: If you say last 12 months, is this from  2014-02-01 or 2014-01-01?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need the last twelve months. Then outer-join the members and count those where the month is in the membership range.

```
select 
  date_format(all_months.someday, '%Y %m') as mymonth,
  count(membership.member_from) as members
from
(
  select current_date as someday
  union all
  select date_add(current_date, interval -1 month)
  union all
  select date_add(current_date, interval -2 month)
  union all
  select date_add(current_date, interval -3 month)
  union all
  select date_add(current_date, interval -4 month)
  union all
  select date_add(current_date, interval -5 month)
  union all
  select date_add(current_date, interval -6 month)
  union all
  select date_add(current_date, interval -7 month)
  union all
  select date_add(current_date, interval -8 month)
  union all
  select date_add(current_date, interval -9 month)
  union all
  select date_add(current_date, interval -10 month)
  union all
  select date_add(current_date, interval -11 month)
) all_months
left join membership
  on date_format(all_months.someday, '%Y %m')
     between
      date_format(membership.member_from, '%Y %m') 
     and
      date_format(membership.member_till, '%Y %m')
group by date_format(all_months.someday, '%Y %m');
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dc5a/10.

As to your future requirement: You can join the membership table twice, once for the members on the first of a month, once for the last of the month (loosing those who participated only some days in the middle of a month). Then add both counts and divide by two.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with SQL Query:

```
SELECT `member_from`, count(id) FROM tbl_test WHERE `member_from` BETWEEN <From date> AND <To date> GROUP BY `member_from`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete with future requirement:

```
SELECT
    d.ymonth,
    COUNT(m.member_from) total,
    COALESCE(SUM(d.fday BETWEEN m.member_from AND m.member_till), 0) total_fom,
    COALESCE(SUM(d.lday BETWEEN m.member_from AND m.member_till), 0) total_lom
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        CAST(@first_day := @first_day + INTERVAL 1 MONTH AS DATE) fday,
        LAST_DAY(@first_day) lday,
        DATE_FORMAT(@first_day, '%Y-%m') ymonth
    FROM
        information_schema.collations
    CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT @first_day := LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL 13 MONTH + INTERVAL 1 DAY) x
    LIMIT 12
    ) d
LEFT JOIN
    membership m
    ON d.lday >= m.member_from
    AND d.fday <= m.member_till
GROUP BY d.ymonth
```

The subquery generates a virtual lookup table with 3 columns:

```
+ ---------- + ---------- + ------- +
| fday       | lday       | ymonth  |
+ ---------- + ---------- + ------- +
| 2014-02-01 | 2014-02-28 | 2014-02 |
|      \/    |      \/    |    \/   |
| 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-31 | 2015-01 |
+ ---------- + ---------- + ------- +
```

Then the membership table can be joined on the overlaps member_from-member_till and the beginning and ending of each month.